# Search a procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to find a stored procedure for eg `Sp_SystemAlert` exists in any database and list names of databases that have that procedure?

Comment: `sp_helptext Sp_SystemAlert` will give you the text of sp if exist otherwise an error!

Comment: for this we have to choose a database. i have many databases actually i need to find in which database this procedure exists

Comment: You could throw in a EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will tell the databases containing the stored procedure.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ##DatabasesContainingSP(dbname sysname, SPName SYSNAME);

EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; 

INSERT INTO ##DatabasesContainingSP
SELECT DISTINCT
       db_name() as dbname, o.name AS Object_Name
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE o.name =''Sp_SystemAlert'';
'

SELECT * FROM ##DatabasesContainingSP
```

Comment: upvote from me, but found you were missing one apostrophe. It supposed to be like this : `WHERE o.name =''Sp_SystemAlert''`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like,

```
CREATE TABLE #Temptable 
(
    dbname varchar(250)
)

EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
            INSERT INTO #Temptable 
            Select ''?''
            FROM sys.procedures 
            Where name = ''<SP_NAME>'' '

SELECT *
FROM #Temptable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Information_schema.routines`

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'  and Routine_Name LIKE 'Sp_SystemAlert%'
```